# How to use CURL to POST Multi-Form File and JSON to Springboot Restful Webservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, curl, pdf-generation, devops

I am trying to use CURL to do a POST request to the following endpoint which takes an html file and a json String as parameter.

Below is the endpoint signature for the first service, which create an html string which is then sent to the second microservice as a json:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/pdf-template", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> bindTemplateData(
            @ApiParam(value = "BindDataRequest payload", required = true)
            @RequestParam MultipartFile template, @RequestParam String templateDataJson) throws IOException {

}
```

The following curl **works** with Json embedded in the curl command:

```
curl --form 'template=@/Users/joe.deen/ms-template-binder/src/main/resources/html-template/Template.html' --form 'templateDataJson={"cost":"2.00","name":"James Milner 2"}' http://localhost:8081//pdf/download | base64 -D > test.pdf
```

But, I will like to read from the json, instead of embedded the data directly e.g.

```
 curl --form 'template=@/Users/joe.deen/ms-template-binder/src/main/resources/html-template/Template.html' --form 'templateDataJson=@/Users/joe.deen/ms-template-binder/src/main/resources/json/test.json' http://localhost:8081//pdf/download | base64 -D > test.pdf
```

The second curl command **is not working**. Its throwing a null pointer in the service.

Please, how can I read from a json file, which is on my mac-os machine and pass as a second parameter to my endpoint, rather than embed the json content which makes the curl command messy. The data is send via a Resttemplate client.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add `;type=application/json` at the end of the json file path as below:

```
curl --form 'template=@/Users/joe.deen/ms-template-binder/src/main/resources/html-template/Template.html' --form 'templateDataJson=@/Users/joe.deen/ms-template-binder/src/main/resources/json/test.json;type=application/json' http://localhost:8081//pdf/download | base64 -D > test.pdf
```

Comment: Hello Madhu, I have tried that and re-tried again. I got the following error: Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST
Warning: (-d, --data) and multipart formpost (-F, --form). Basically, I am passing the html template as a multipart file, but the JSON is a string parameter to the endpoint. I want to specific location of the JSON file and read in the data via Curl. Embedding the json string in Curl works. But, It makes the Curl command big and messy.

Comment: @olatom I've updated the answer. Can you try this and confirm please?

Comment: @olatom did it help?